# Lookup formatting in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

and the screenshot below:

[image]

I want cell E4 from screenshot 1 to turn yellow because:

1. The Overall level is 58
   and
2. Level 1 is 1
   and
3. Level 2 is 2

Notice if you lookup level1=1 and level2=2 in the matrix from the second screenshot then the value is 58.

Can I do this? I have tried conditional formatting and got nowhere.  Do I have to use VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the 58 from the lookup table is easy:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, 1+C4, FALSE)
```

You could then add a conditional format rule "Use a formula to determine..." and make the formula this:

```
=(E4 >= VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, 1+C4, FALSE))
```

With one rule, you will only get one colour. To get the 4 different colours, you must create four different conditional formatting rules for the same area:

```
=AND(E4 >= VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, 1+C4, FALSE), B4 = 1, C4 = 1)   >  red rule
=AND(E4 >= VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, 1+C4, FALSE), B4 = 1, C4 = 2)   >  yellow rule
=AND(E4 >= VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, 1+C4, FALSE), B4 = 2, C4 = 1)   >  beige rule
=AND(E4 >= VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, 1+C4, FALSE), B4 = 2, C4 = 2)   >  green rule
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to change the colour dynamically when using the formula based conditional formatting. If you have many different colours, it will get tedious quick to input a rule for every colour. In that case, you might want to try one of the multi-color conditional formatting that changes based on the numerical value of a cell. In a new adjacent cell put: =IF(E4 >= VLOOKUP(B4, sheet1!$B$9:$E$10, B4 + (C4-1)*2,0)

Comment: Thanks.  Could you clarify what you mean in your comment?

Comment: There is a conditional format (color scales?) where you can set the color for different number ranges all in one rule. I.e. F4 >= 4 green, >= 3 yellow, >= 2 beige and >=1 red. Now put the formula above in F4. It will return 0 if the value in E2 is less than its lookup level (according to level 1 & 2) and 1..4 if larger according to the colour it should  be.